# Different Views for the same Model in PyQt

Tags: qt, treeview, pyqt

I have a question about multiple views for a particular model in PyQt.

Currently, I have a TreeView setup to display a model inheriting from StandardItemModel. There are three types of StandardItems in the model: `Alpha`, `Beta`, `Gamma`. They are parented in the TreeView like so

```
+ Alpha
|
\------+ Beta
|      |
|      \------+ Gamma
|      \------+ Gamma
|      \------+ Gamma
\------+ Beta
|      |
|      \------+ Gamma
|      \------+ Gamma
|      \------+ Gamma
```

Currently, I only have the `Alpha` and `Beta` levels shown in a TreeView. What I'd like is for another TreeView to populate with `Gamma` values depending on which Beta object I have selected in the first View.

I've figured that I can do this with `setRootIndex()`, and just check if the selected item at the index in the first TreeView is an instance of the `Gamma` item class. However, this only happens when I have selected a `Beta` item in the first TreeView, otherwise, the second TreeView just shows everything.

How would I make sure that the second TreeView *only* populates when a `Gamma` item in the first TreeView is selected?