# Qt: remove model from view

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractitemview

We usually set view's model in Qt like this:
`view->setModel(model);`

But is there any way to *remove* a model from view? I mean literally leave a view empty like it was just created and there was not any model set to it yet.

If you ask me a *reason* of my desire, I have a pretty much similar case as in this guy's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698182/different-views-for-the-same-model-in-pyqt). And when first view has no selection or it is empty/invalid/whatever, I want to make the second view show literally nothing: no headers, columns, rubbish data. Removing a model from the view seems to be pretty reasonable in that case.

I've tried a dirty hack:
`*view = QTableView();`
But Qt took care about such evil things and made `operator=` private.

Comment: Does [`view->setModel(nullptr)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setModel) not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the source of `QAbstractItemView::setModel()`:

```
d->model = (model ? model : QAbstractItemModelPrivate::staticEmptyModel());
```

It looks like if you pass a null pointer, it will internally use some dummy model fallback. So null pointers are supported and that's a valid way to go to "unset" the current model.